# Please change comment notification to notify multiple people

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow more than one @name notification per comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45273/allow-more-than-one-name-notification-per-comment)

A fellow stacker tried to [notify me when he left a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241270/a-file-server-and-its-associated-clients/6241298#6241298):

> @Roland and @sarnold Is it possible to get a rough sample code so that I am more clear. Thanks for the trouble

He was not aware that [only the first person is notified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020). (And I'd long since forgotten this restriction.)

A more compelling use is the frequently-seen poor initial question; several people leave comments requesting more information; the questioner updates the question, and wishes to notify everyone who asked for more details that the question has been improved. Why should this case require three, four, five, N comments?

Please allow notifying multiple participants via a single comment. The rest of the Stack feels so magical, this restriction feels archaic.