# Notifying two people at once in a comment

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow more than one @name notification per comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45273/349538)

---

I've read [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45273/349538), but I don't think it's a duplicate because it's asking to make several `@name`s in the same comment notify both users mentioned. The feature allowing several `@name`s in the same comment just got unimplemented. I'm asking why it's been unimplemented (and asking for it back). Sort of different, right?

The *closest* match would be this one: [Don't block comments with two @lerts if one of them is @postowner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99015/dont-block-comments-with-two-alerts-if-one-of-them-is-postowner) , except that it talks about @postowner. (My question is more about the general case.)

---

Recently, I discovered I couldn't provide the following comment:

> @Whovever [...] Like @NameOfSomePerson said, [...].

If I were @NameOfSomePerson, I'd like to get a notification because someone used my name. Someone's talking about me!! Maybe they're misinterpreting what I'd said earlier, and saying the wrong stuff? I'd like to be able to clarify/correct that, but I can only do that if I get notified.

---

**EDIT 2:** [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94872/please-change-comment-notification-to-notify-multiple-people)'s a nice example:

> @Roland and @sarnold Is it possible to get a rough sample code so that I am more clear. Thanks for the trouble

(Assume @Ronald is not the answerer or asker.)

Comment: Did you look at existing posts on Meta at *all*? Pointless arguments about comment notifications have been everywhere recently.

Comment: @camccann Can you give me some examples? I haven't been on Meta recently.

Comment: Just skim the recent questions list. Or look at the links under "Related" over to the right.

Comment: @camccann I've looked through the **Related** section, but I can't find any that match my question exactly. (The fact that this feature doesn't work anymore; [one of the questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45273/allow-more-than-one-name-notification-per-comment) is asking for this feature [ **last year** ], which was implemented, but now seems to be "unimplemented" for unknown reasons.) Could you provide some example links?

Comment: It's not a matter of exact match, it's the whole ongoing argument over how comment notifications work in general, the gist of which should make it clear that your request is unlikely to be well-received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature request has been made several times before, but always for notifying multiple people of the *same* thing, as far as I can tell. If you're saying two different things to two different people, go ahead and leave *two different comments*.

Comment: The @ was not used for user names, rather they were part of a query. For example if you are working with stored procedures in SQL, all parameters are preceded by @. You can not post such a query because of this limitation. This is a bug

Comment: @Dave - If that is in fact what muntoo is talking about, it needs to be made a *lot* clearer in the question, and should be a bug report instead of a feature request. His question still seems to me to be about notifying with usernames though.

Comment: @Dave If you are using `@`s in code in comments, then they should be formatted as code (i.e. the code should be surrounded by backticks). Backticks disable this feature, so using Markdown correctly should not cause any problems.

Comment: `@myname, @yourname` if it gets posted then this problem is fixed. I was the first one who spotted this but never filed it as bug. The message probably needs to be a little bit more clear.

Comment: @Dave: Concerning clarity of the message see also [Don't block comments with two ‍@alerts if one of them is ‍@postowner](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99015).