# @-function in comment-replies

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow more than one @name notification per comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45273/allow-more-than-one-name-notification-per-comment)

Why is it only possible to react on only one of the earlier comments?

In this question: [UISearchBar calls API everytime a letter is typed and not on Searchbutton click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096617/uisearchbar-calls-api-everytime-a-letter-is-typed-and-not-on-searchbutton-click#comment11424950_9096617)

I would've loved to use the @-function to both persons.

Is this intentional? Why?

Comment: Yes, it's intentional.  I believe this feature request has been shot down many times.  Example: [Allow more than one name notification per comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45273/allow-more-than-one-name-notification-per-comment)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'd love to see it as well, but throw some weight behind the original (more votes, put a bounty, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's intentional. As per [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work):

> You can explicitly notify one (1) other commenter, editor, or ♦ moderator who closed a question

It goes on to say;

> Comments containing more than one @name [are blocked](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/should-we-discourage-the-use-of-multiple-redundant-username-pings-in-comments/2615#2615) unless they contain a backtick `. In the latter case, only the first name mentioned using the @name syntax will be notified. For example, @alice @bob Hi!` will notify Alice (if she has participated in that post), but not Bob.

Yes, it sucks. Yes, we've asked it to be reverted. <sup>and no, Jeff won't hear us</sup>

Comment: Hehe shame. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: well, the multiple name block is there because people asked for it.. if you don't block it, people will open one zillion meta posts asking why it doesn't "work"