# Make invalid @user comments fail more explicitly

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies

Currently, if I attempt to notify a user who is not eligible for notification (i.e., they haven't commented, edited, or done something in [this list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/139256)), the failure is completely silent. I, the comment poster, never know that the user wasn't notified. I propose that the failure be more explicit, and that the comment either fail or that a notice is placed near the comment while it's being typed if the notify attempt will fail. Something like this (which I just hacked together in 2 min using Firebug, so Don't Judge Me, Bro™):

> [image: Suggested idea for explicit showing of failed user notification]

Comment: One way this might backfire is that: users who are trying to PM "their own personal tech support" will now know to seek out a different post for an even more inappropriate comment.  Might be better to let them get frustrated at the lack of response -- sort of like a mini "Hell ban".

Comment: Yeah, but for users (like [me](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/51/73)) who just assume the system always works, it's pretty confusing.

Comment: Ah, but you see, for the rare case when an innocent user is caught unawares, your example shows that a friendly, neighborhood mod stepped in and showed them the light. (^_^)

Comment: Interesting idea, but I'm not sure that this happens all that often. @-addressing someone is only treated as a notification in specific cases and it's not guaranteed that using @ in other contexts is actually an attempt to notify a user or just some text that happens to have an @ in it.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know the comment @ comments didn't work sometimes.

Comment: I'm not sure how much this is browser-oriented, but I think that there is correlation between the auto-completion when you type "@" and if the user will be notified (i.e. no completion = no notification).

Comment: @CharlesMorisset: Don't think so.  If you are posting comments and it's just you and the OP, the auto completion will not fire, but the OP still gets notified.

Comment: @BrockAdams Yes, you're right, the OP (of the question or answer on which the comment thread is) will always receive notification. But for the other users, I guess you need the completion. Also, it seems that you can only one completion per comment. Does that mean that there will be only one notification per comment?

Comment: @CharlesMorisset, Yes there is only one reply per comment (not counting Q OP and A OP (if applicable) ).  This sad state of affairs is "by design" despite [much clamoring for improvement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45273/148310).

Comment: @BrockAdams I have the feeling that SE is somehow extremely conservative on the subject. Although I can understand the potential misuse and abuse having easier inter-users communications, I'm sure they have enough talented developers to come up with a practical, safe and non-conservative solution.

Comment: I'd prefer linkification of @notifications. This has the positive side effect that you can see that a notification didn't work, because it wasn't turned into a link.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - That's fine as well, so long as the failure isn't silent.

Comment: @CharlesMorisset - I agree with you re: conservative, and I'm very curious why.