# Replying to several users

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow more than one @name notification per comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45273/allow-more-than-one-name-notification-per-comment)

I'm a bit confused and would like to know the reason why you are only able to reply to one person? I had several situations lately, where it would have been handy if it was possible to notify several users at once. Whhat are the reasons for introducing this restriction?

edit:

It's not that I want to have an extensive discussion in the comment section, mostly it's just a short hint or notification you would like to assure to get read (point out a mistake or something like that). Atm I would post 2 comments (which I assume is not how it should be) rather then starting an unneccessary chat.

Comment: Reply to more than one has been declined: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45273/allow-more-than-one-name-notification-per-comment?rq=1 the specific reason isn't in that post, I forget where it is

Comment: @Ben Well, that is the question i have. WHY? I searched and found no reasonable answer.

Comment: AFAICT, ROI. I've also wanted to notify multiple users on occasions. Either way, *this* question is a dupe :)

Answer (score 2):

This is what [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) is for. Discussions are not supposed to be held in comments, as they quickly clog up the readability of the post.

If you must have a discussion, invite the users to a private room in chat. It's much more reliable, quicker, and is meant for that sort of thing.

Comment: well, sometimes it's not worth it to start a new chat for that. E.g. when it's just a note or a hint. Atm I would most likely post two comments which is not how it should be...