# Why can we tag only one user in a comment?

Tags: support, tags, comments, users

Why can't we tag more than one user in comment? Is that a restriction on some low reputation users or is it for all?

Comment: @Oded - [Seems exact duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164681/187824).