# Have the comment reply autocomplete popup for more than one user

Tags: feature-request, comment-replies

Suppose there are two users, say **Bob** and **John** who made comments on my post.

There is a situation I would like to address both of them in a single comment. However I can address them by `@Bob` and `@John`, but only typing the second person name (in this case John) **manually**, i.e. autocomplete will not popup.

The autocomplete will only show the first person name (in this case Bob) automatically but not the second person name.

Can the popup be displayed for the second user as well?

Comment: Pavan I edited per my understanding, if I was wrong and you mean sending notification to more than one user feel free to roll back and I'll mark it as dupe of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45273/152859).

Comment: @ShadowWizard No I would like to keep your Edit. It is Great!

Comment: Trouble with this is I think it would give the user the impression that both people they tagged were going to receive notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Only one person can be notified using `@username` per comment](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/).

Adding an additional autocomplete would imply you can notify two people, when in reality you can't. Adding the autocomplete without adding notification of multiple people would be a bit counter-productive, but notifying multiple users [has already been requested and declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45273/allow-more-than-one-name-notification-per-comment).

In the meantime, what you can do is:

Make a comment:

> Hey @Bob and John, thanks for the edits!

Edit the comment:

> Hey Bob and @John, thanks for the edits!

Then both will be notified (and when you edit and delete the `@` from in front of Bob, putting an `@` will give you autocomplete for John.

Comment: Nice tip, had wondered if making an edit like that would make Bob's notification disappear.