# Can we make it possible to tag more than one user in the same comment?

Tags: feature-request, comment-replies

I know there must be a good reason why the one tag limit must be in place, but I can't really see a good reason why. From my perspective, I often would like to reply to two or more users with the same message, but to do so I have to write to separate comments.

Could someone please enlighten my as to why the one tag limit exists, and/or can we make it possible to tag multiple users in a comment?

Comment: The reason why this isn't allowed is explained in this declined feature request: [Allow more than one @name notification per comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45273/allow-more-than-one-name-notification-per-comment)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Thanks for the link; however, I think I have to say no. Part of this question is "can we start being able to notify more users now?" The answer was no in 2010, but perhaps the answer will be different this time. Also, on that thread I saw the vast majority of users in favor of the idea, so I would say the topic deserves a new thread on 2019-2020.

Comment: Yeah, if you want this request to be reconsidered, you should [edit] this to do three things: explicitly indicate you're aware of the earlier declined request, address the reasons for declining it at the time (e.g. why they don't apply today), and (optional, but recommended) introduce new arguments for allowing it. Otherwise, if a request doesn't contain any more arguments than what are in an earlier declined request, it will be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog It's severely unclear why the request was denied in the first place. It just says "No valid use cases" without any analysis for why any of the mentioned use cases in the thread were not valid.

Comment: @rockwalrus-stopharmingMonica So then add a list of use cases and explain how they're valid.